# VIM copying to clipboard and pasting to Notepad not working

Tags: vim, editor, clipboard

I'm trying to select a block of text from the Unix VIM editor in console (I'm using Putty) and paste it into notepad. I've already read all the threads here and nothing is working.

What I've done so far:

- sudo apt-get install vim-gtk   (+clipboard +xterm_clipboard activated)
- vimrc file: maped "+y to Ctrl-c (for convienience)
- V to select block of text in visual mode (for example 132 lines)
- Ctrl-c to copy text (the mapping above works, so it says "132 lines yanked")

**PROBLEM:**
When I go to Windows Notepad try to paste the text, nothing happens. Why and how to fix?

Thanks

Kind regards

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing should get your yanked lines into the X11 copy buffer on the remote machine, but to get as far as Notepad on your local machine you need a couple more pieces.

1. An X server that will treat the X11 and Windows clipboards as
   unified.  I believe Xming will do this, probably others as well.
2. X11 Forwarding enabled in putty (and allowed by the ssh server).

All other things being equal, it's a **lot** easier to just copy lines in Putty and paste in the traditional way.  If this breaks formatting you need to preserve, you might consider working on the remote file and copying it to your workstation using scp or some other means.

Comment: If the file consists of multiple pages/screens, then copying lines in Putty in the traditional way seems difficult! Because you can copy lines of one screen at a time only! Mouse scrolling isn't possible here if I use `vim example.log`